How deal with big trace which can be divise in OpenTelemetry?
I have a worker, which call a function foo every x secs.
I would like to trace every call of this function foo, to monitoring how things go to each call.
I am using c# activity to monitoring, and it goes in OpenTelemetry collector / backend / etc...
I watch these trace on Grafana.
My function foo is similar to :
void foo()
{
  using var activity = activitySource.StartActivity("foo");

  var userIDList = GetUserIDList(); // Some span are create here

  foreach (var userID in userIDList)
  {
    someActionOnUser(userID); // lot of span are create here
  }
}

The final trace is heavy (something like 10Mo), and I would like to reduce this size because backend has a size limit (I could grow up this limit, but I search a better solution...).
My idea was to :

Create a parent trace A for each loop iteration (which will catch span create in someActionOnUser)
Create a span B for parent trace "foo" (which will not catch span create in someActionOnUser)
Set up a Span link from A to B and B to A

In C#, Span link is Activity Link.
But in C#, you can set Activity Link only when you create an activity (link to activity code source), so this solution is not really possible...
I found this discussion, with the suggestion to add a function AddLinks in activity, and the problem with this.
So I suppose this idea is not really good (I wonder if it's not an anti-pattern...).
I don't think I'm the first one with this problem, but I don't find many resources about this.
I suspect I have a bad strategy to deal with that.
How people deal with this problem ?

This is more of an asking for opinions question really, there are lots of options. before it get's closed... let me say that you should consider how you want to debug this, what queries are you running against the traces or individual spans, or what do you want to see to get to the bottom of issues. Use that to guide you.  Also, likely in .NET 9, there will be an AddLinks, it was just merged recently.

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/docs/trace/links-creation-with-new-activities - Check this doc, it has some examples on how to achieve this.
(Note: AddLink API is coming later this year : https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues/5273)

I check this one, but it set link only from children to parent (not parent to children)....
Thanks for the link to the issue !
